# get "Please correct warning compiling" android debug but I have -dontwarn in Proguard file

Tags: android, proguard

When I compile my app I get an org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':******:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardFor*****Debug'. As you can see I have all the -dontwarn  notation in the proguard file but when I get the debug warnings it looks like I did not add them.
I get these warning for all my dependencies:

> Warning: com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.Graphics2D

Where am I going wrong?

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.******.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3
        versionName "5.0.3"

        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so"
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libBlinkBarcode.so"
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libsdkwrap.so"
        }
        manifestPlaceholders = [screenOrientation: "portrait"]
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }

    flavorDimensions "Main"

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            applicationId "com.contactable.app.seriti"
            manifestPlaceholders = [screenOrientation: "portrait"]
            dimension "Main"
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://maven.microblink.com' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/swi.jar')
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.12'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.kailashdabhi:om-recorder:1.1.5'
    implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.0.4'
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    annotationProcessor 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    annotationProcessor 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    annotationProcessor 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.kailashdabhi:om-recorder:1.1.5'
    annotationProcessor 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'
    implementation files('libs/PDFRenderer-0.9.0.jar')
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation project(':ims_android-release')

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is my proguard file

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-optimizations !method/inlining/*
-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
        public static *** d(...);
        public static *** i(...);
        public static *** v(...);
    }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keep class com.itextpdf.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.itextpdf.**

-keep class com.google.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.google.**

-keep class org.parceler.** {*;}
-dontwarn org.parceler.**

-keep class com.android.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.android.**

-keep class com.loopj.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.loopj.**

-keep class com.squareup.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.squareup.**

-keep class com.daimajia.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.daimajia.**

-keep class com.github.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.github.**

-keep class joda-time.** {*;}
-dontwarn joda-time.**

-keep class com.kailashdabhi.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.kailashdabhi.**

-keep class io.card.** {*;}
-dontwarn io.card.**

-keep class com.journeyapps.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.journeyapps.**

-keep class me.leolin.** {*;}
-dontwarn me.leolin.**

-keep class java.** {*;}
-dontwarn java.**

-keep class com.samsung.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.samsung.**

-keep class javax.** {*;}
-dontwarn javax.**

-keep class java.awt.Graphics2D.** {*;}
-dontwarn java.awt.**

-keep class org.apache.** {*;}
-dontwarn org.apache.**

-keep class rx.** {*;}
-dontwarn rx.**

-keep class org.bouncycastle.** {*;}
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**

-keep class retrofit.** {*;}
-dontwarn retrofit.**

-keep class com.contactable.app.barcode.camera.** {*;}


-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-dontnote android.support.v4.**


-keepclassmembers class com.contactable.app.** {
    public static final <fields>;
}

-keep com.sun.pdfview.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.sun.pdfview.**

-keep okio.**
-dontwarn okio.**

-keep org.joda.time.** {*;}
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**

-keep test.** {*;}
-dontwarn test.**
```

And this is error log:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':contactable:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForSeritiDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:196)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:253)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:63)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:173)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:282)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the proguard rules file was not being found when building for a specific flavor dimension. Not sure why.

Solved by specifying the root folder when loading the proguard rules file as such:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), "$project.rootDir/proguard-rules.pro"
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), "$project.rootDir/proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else, took a whole day to figure out.